How should I configure redis in aws lambda?
I am using the ioredis to connect to my redis in elastic-cache. I wonder is there any recommended config? Since every lambda will create a new connection, would the max connection of redis reached if there are many open connections when the traffic spikes?
Is there something like RDS proxy for redis in aws?
